# Broken system after update

Tags: release-juno, updates

I have Elementary OS 5 Juno installed in my desktop and my laptop and some hours ago I did an update of the system and after restarting the equipment they do not complete the boot.

At the moment I am trying to make them back up and I will put more details about the hardware as soon as possible.

I am assuming that the problem is related to the update because when trying to do a reinstallation of the system it presents several errors after downloading the packages, during the execution of the installation scripts.

Installing another distribution on the same hardware worked normally.

Desktop Hardware: AMD FX8320x, VGA AMD R9 380x 4GB Gigabyte, Mobo Gigabyte 970A-DS3P, 8GB DDR3 (4x2 2200mhz), SSD Sandisk 480GB 'SSDA480G", USB microsoft mouse and keyboard

Laptop: Dell Inspiron 3421 (i3, 1Tb HD, 12Gb ram)

Customizations:

- I'm using the [OIBAF](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) repo for updated AMD/intel drivers in both setups
- In desktop I'm using the kernel 5.x from Ubuntu kernel testing repo
- My laptop is almost elementary Juno "vanilla" only added Gimp and some Snaps (skype, telegram, shotcut) - but none of theese have any update in days.
- On desktop I'm running Windows 10 in the same SSD with no problems

**Update**:
As I commented, I have a Windows 10 installed in the same HD as this Juno and to eliminate hardware problems, I just ran several stress sequences with HeavyLoad and the PC stayed 10 minutes at maximum memory and processor load without getting unstable .

[image]

---

I still can not explain what happened with Elementary that was installed, but it was only possible to perform a new installation after deleting the existing partitions with GParted.

At the moment I'm using Juno with official sources and flathub without any problems, both on desktop and notebook.

Comment: Why not try reverting a few of those customizations first? Like the custom kernel and removing that extra repo.

Comment: The system had become completely unusable after the upgrade I mentioned and now I can not complete any installation of Elementary on that hardware. Ubuntu 19.04 installed normally.